# Firestore compound whereField query does not work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have built this compound whereField query but for some reason it does not appear to be applying any of the filters. I pass dynamic data into the whereFields using a searchCriteria field. This is correctly changing but no matter the combination, I always get all the records back. Any idea what is going on?

```
    let dbCollection = db.collection(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.COLLECTION_ITEM)

    dbCollection.whereField(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_OWNER_FIELD, isEqualTo: searchCriteria.owner)

    dbCollection.whereField(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_CATEGORY_FIELD, isEqualTo: searchCriteria.category)
    dbCollection.order(by: Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_DATE_CREATED_FIELD, descending: false)
```

THE DATA

```
category "need" (string)
count 10
date_created 1586663033.023617
name "Needs 1"
owner "INvSUJyBwecZgZg0o33dLu3VgGt2"

category "stock" (string)
count 10
date_created 1586664033.023617
name "Stock 1"
owner "INvSUJyBwecZgZg0o33dLu3VgGt2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling whereField on a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query) doesn't change the Query object that you call it on.  It creates a new Query object with the filter applied.  So, you should either follow the pattern in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) the shows them chained together:

```
let query = db
    .collection(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.COLLECTION_ITEM)
    .whereField(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_OWNER_FIELD, isEqualTo: searchCriteria.owner)
    .whereField(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_CATEGORY_FIELD, isEqualTo: searchCriteria.category)
    .order(by: Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_DATE_CREATED_FIELD, descending: false)
```

Or remember the new Query object every time you call it:

```
var query = db.collection(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.COLLECTION_ITEM)
query = query.whereField(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_OWNER_FIELD, isEqualTo: searchCriteria.owner)
query = query.whereField(Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_CATEGORY_FIELD, isEqualTo: searchCriteria.category)
query = query.order(by: Constants.FirebaseFirestore.ITEM_DATE_CREATED_FIELD, descending: false)
```